# Icom 705 USB link to Raspberry Pi4 running OpenCPN

Tags: ham-radio-deluxe, marine

Anyone have a similar setup?  If so what kind of data our of the 705 can we leverage onto the NMEA 2K network (on a boat)?  Also, (going the other direction) is there a Debian Bullseye HAM app that can auto tune the freq on the 705?

I'm about to dig into this but thought I'd ask the guru's here!

thx,

Comment: Welcome to the site! Would you edit your question to also share your country and license class so the community can get you relevant answers? Thank you!

Comment: Are you receiving only with the 705?